# How to build and use my own datasource protocol in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, datasource

I want to give users an option to customize header view of my custom view component library.

So I would like to follow the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol and trying to implement something like that.

// CustomView.swift

```
protocol CustomViewDatasource: class {
   func heightForHeader(in view: CustomView) -> CGFloat
   func headerView(in view: CustomView) -> UIView
}

class CustomView: UIView {
   weak var dataSource: CustomViewDatasource?
   /// How can I draw the custom header view passing by dataSource?
}
```

// ViewController.swift

```
extension ViewController: CustomViewDatasource {

  ...

  func headerView(in view: CustomView) -> UIView {
    let headerView = UIView()
    headerView.backgroundColor = .green
    return headerView
  }

  func heightForHeader(in view: CustomView) -> CGFloat {
    return 150
  }
}
```

How can I draw the header view passing by dataSource?

I've no idea. I'd appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: making extensions of the protocol implementing default functions and variables

Comment: @azinwi Of course, I should. I am asking how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By calling it within your `CustomView`.

```
class CustomView: UIView {

    private let headerViewTag = 42

    weak var dataSource: CustomViewDatasource? {
        didSet {
            updateHeaderView()
        }
    }

    private func updateHeaderView() {
        // remove the old one
        viewWithTag(headerViewTag)?.removeFromSuperview()

        // ask for customized data
        let headerView = dataSource?.headerView(in: self) ?? defaultHeaderView()
        let headerViewHeight = dataSource?.heightForHeader(in: self) ?? 100

        headerView?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        headerView?.tag = headerViewTag

        if let headerView = headerView {
            addSubview(headerView)
            // set your constraints
        }
    }

    private func defaultHeaderView() -> UIView {
        // default header view's implementation here
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks @xius! This is what I was looking for! :+1